# golang null.String decoding not working correctly

Tags: sql, go

Trying to fix this problem i'm having with my api im building.

db:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts (
        uuid UUID UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
        first_name varchar(150),
);



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS workorders CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS workorders (
        uuid UUID UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
        work_date timestamp WITH time zone,
        requested_by UUID REFERENCES contacts (uuid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,

);
```

struct:

https://gopkg.in/guregu/null.v3

```
type WorkorderNew struct {
    UUID               string      `json:"uuid"`
    WorkDate           null.Time   `json:"work_date"`
    RequestedBy        null.String `json:"requested_by"`
}
```

api code:

```
workorder := &models.WorkorderNew{}
if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(workorder); err != nil {
    log.Println("decoding fail", err)
}
// fmt.Println(NewUUID())
u2, err := uuid.NewV4()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to generate UUID: %v", err)
}

q := `
            INSERT
            INTO workorders
                (uuid,
                work_date,
                requested_by
                )
            VALUES
                ($1,$2,$3)
            RETURNING uuid;`

statement, err := global.DB.Prepare(q)
global.CheckDbErr(err)

fmt.Println("requested by", workorder.RequestedBy)

lastInsertID := ""
err = statement.QueryRow(
    u2,
    workorder.WorkDate,
    workorder.RequestedBy,
).Scan(&lastInsertID)
global.CheckDbErr(err)

json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(lastInsertID)
```

When I send an API request with null as the value it works as expected
but when i try to send a "" as the value for the null.String or the null.Time it fails

works:

```
{  
   "work_date":"2016-12-16T19:00:00Z",
   "requested_by":null
}
```

not working:

```
{  
   "work_date":"2016-12-16T19:00:00Z",
   "requested_by":""
}
```

Basically when i call the QueryRow and save to database the workorder.RequestedBy value should be a null and not the "" value im getting
thanks

Comment: What does *"it fails"* or *"not working"* mean? Are you getting an error? If so, please include that error in your question. Are you getting a result different from what you expect? If so, please include the expected and the actual result in the question.

Comment: @mkopriva i'm expecting when i do the queryrow it to save RequestedBy as a null in the database and not to save it as  "" ( which fails with my schema)

Comment: Then do not use `null.String` but implement your own custom type. Since in json an empty string `""` is not the same as `null`, the behaviour of `null.String` is correct. So if your requirements are different from what `null.String` supports then simply do not use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to treat empty strings as nulls you have at least two options.

"Extend" `null.String`:

```
type MyNullString struct {
    null.String
}

func (ns *MyNullString) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if string(data) == `""` {
        ns.Valid = false
        return nil
    }
    ns.String.UnmarshalJSON(data)
}
```

Or use `NULLIF` in the query:

```
INSERT INTO workorders (
    uuid
    , work_date
    , requested_by
) VALUES (
    $1
    , $2
    , NULLIF($3, '')
)
RETURNING uuid
```

---

**Update**:

To extend the `null.Time` you have to understand that the type of [`null.Time.Time`](https://github.com/guregu/null/blob/v3.4.0/time.go#L14) is a *struct*. The builtin [`len`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len) function works on slices, arrays, pointers to arrays, maps, channels, and strings. Not structs. So in this case you can check the `data` argument, which is a byte slice, by converting it to a string and comparing it to a string that *contains* an empty string, i.e. it has two double quotes and nothing else.

```
type MyNullTime struct {
    null.Time
}

func (ns *MyNullTime) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if string(data) == `""` {
        ns.Valid = false
        return nil
    }
    return ns.Time.UnmarshalJSON(data)
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for first solution was perfect. I've tried to implement it for null.time but im a bit lost on that too could you possible tell me how to do that one too?

func (ns *MyNullTime) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
 if err := ns.Time.UnmarshalJSON(data); err != nil {
  return err
 }
 ns.Valid = len(ns.Time.Time) > 0 // if empty, set as valid=false
 return nil
} dosent seem to work

Comment: @Trentfrompunchbowl1 I've added an update to the answer, try it and let me know if it works because I haven't tested it or anything.

Comment: @mkoprive works like a charm and thanks again for your help.... my brain has melted all day from trying to figure out what i was doing wrong